# Customize visible area of HTML element clipped by SVG <clipPath>

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an HTML element that I clip using a path in an external SVG, which makes for a setup like this:

CSS:

```
video {
  clip-path: url(path.svg#clip)
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <video src="foo.png" width="480" height="150" />
</body>
</html>
```

SVG:

```
<svg width="480px" height="92px" viewBox="0 0 480 92">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <path d="…"></path>
            <path d="…"></path>
            <path d="…"></path>
        </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Note that the image I want to clip is slightly higher than the path that clips it. How can I position the image's position to change which region is visible?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using svg all the way? It would prevent the use of CSS `clip-path`, have better browser support and make the image positioning easy.

Comment: Yes, the reason is that I'm clipping a video. I'll update the code to clarify this.

Comment: with html5 you can nest html > svg > html. so using svg directly should work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem by wrapping the `<video>` inside another container and applying the mask to it. The container is positioned relatively and using absolute positioning i can then move the video around inside it.

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: url(path.svg#clip)
}

.container video {
  position: absolute;
  /* … */
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <video src="foo.png" width="480" height="150" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Another option would have been `mask-clip`  or something similar, as described on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask).